# How can I create an AWS EMR security configuration using a custom resource with CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, emr, aws-cloudformation

How can I create an AWS EMR security configuration using a custom resource with CloudFormation?

```
"EMRConfig": 
      "Type": "Custom::EMRConfig",
      "Properties": 
        "ServiceToken": "Fn::GetAtt" : ["EMRConfigFunction", "Arn"]
        "clusterId" :  "Ref" : "EMRC522DV"
```

Comment: Wondering, where could we set security configuration like In-Transit and at-Rest in above syntax. I am finding it tough to apply security configuration to EMR cluster from Cloudformation.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track assuming `EMRConfigFunction` is the logical name of a Lambda function that you plan to code. When you place your snippet in the CloudFormation template and update your stack, CloudFormation will trigger `EMRConfigFunction` and pass it some parameters (*e.g.* `RequestType = 'Create'`, `clusterId = <your-cluster-id>` that you're passing from the CF template etc.). `EMRConfigFunction` will then have to go ahead and create the security configuration based on the available parameters using AWS SDK (*e.g.* `boto3` in case the Lambda function is written in Python), construct a response in a specific format that CF expects and write the response at a pre-signed URL (that location will be accessible as a `ResponseURL` param in the Lambda function). I'd recommend going through the AWS docs for [Lambda backed custom resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) (and tutorial on the same page) for more details, as well as the docs for [creating a security configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-encryption-enable-security-configuration.html#emr-encryption-creating-configuration).